# When on click a few seconds on recycleview run a snackbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

i have a recycleview, When on click a few seconds on recycleview, run a snackbar. how to make it?
I am confused looking for keywords to search in google.
That i can just this :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://bls.hol.es/" + list_data.get(position).get("poto"))
            .crossFade()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.imghape);
    final String namamu=list_data.get(position).get("nama");
    holder.txthape.setText(namamu);
    holder.txtalamat.setText(list_data.get(position).get("alamat"));
    // Set onclicklistener pada view tvTitle (TextView)
    holder.txthape.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked element "+namamu, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Tanks..

Comment: make one int variable and inside onclick make it ++ after certain value call snackbar

Comment: tanks. i will try it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **setOnLongClickListener** instead of **setOnClickListener**

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v,"Please enter a name",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

So your code becomes

```
holder.txthape.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    Snackbar.make(v, "Clicked element "+namamu, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Sorri i forget.

Answer (score 1):

If i did understand your answer well what are you looking for is **OnLongClickListener**, here is a [link to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html). You just need to replace your click listener like this

```
holder.txthape.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked element "+namamu, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```